# Is there a link between fractional derivatives and sobolev spaces $H^s$ for $s$ fractional?

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

We define for example $H^{1/2}(\mathbb R)$ as the set $$\left\{f\in L^2(\mathbb R)\mid \int_{\mathbb R}(1+|\xi|^2)^{1/2}|\hat f(\xi)|\mathrm d \xi<\infty  \right\},$$
where $\hat f$ is the Fourier transform of $f$. As well, you can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus) that we can define $$\frac{d^{1/2}}{dx^{1/2}}f(x)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(1/2)}\int_0^x(x-t)^{-1/2}f(t)dt$$
when $f$ has sufficiently good condition (we can also generalize this for $\frac{d^\alpha }{dx^\alpha } f$ for $\alpha >0$).

My question is : we don't have explicitly the $1/2-$derivative of $f$ when it's in $H^{1/2}$ but if we can catch it, and if the function is regular enough, would it be the same derivative ?

Comment: Yes, this works, and it's essentially explained in the wikipedia article in the section "Laplace transforms;" you really want to use Fourier transforms here, but the calculations work the same way. (Your exponents are off in the definition of $H^{1/2}$.)